# app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug in Android studio 3.0.1

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, dex, appium-android

**Messages Gradle build:**

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

**Here is the gradle build files:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {

        compileSdkVersion 26
        defaultConfig {

            minSdkVersion 26
            targetSdkVersion 26
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
            multiDexEnabled true

        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {

        implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso 
        core:3.0.1'
        implementation files('libs/bsh-core-2.0b4.jar')
        implementation files('libs/selenium-java-2.3.0.jar')
        implementation files('libs/selenium-remote-driver-3.0.0.jar')
        // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client
        implementation  group: 'io.appium', name: 'java-client', version: '5.0.4'

    }
```

Comment: check this : https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex

Answer (score 4):

This error is generic, can be caused by many things

> java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

First, you need to know what error you have. So, you have two choices:

- **CMD:** go to android workspaces and put **gradlew installDebug --stacktrace** (optional --info --debug)
- **Run or build project:** go to File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler and write in Command-line Options: **--stacktrace --debug**

Next, you need to go in the part where says Cause by (Last of then because u can have more than one error).

If you have:

> Caused by: com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536

Then you need to put this, like comments before said but if your mindSdkVersion >= 21

```
android {
    defaultConfig 
    {
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
}
```

If your minSdkVersion < 21 you need put also this

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
```

More info [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex?hl=es-419)

Answer (score 3):

Try this on your `build.gradle(Module: app)` file:

```
android {
    defaultConfig 
    {
        ...
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem were duplicate packages. I used react-native link and the app didn't recognize that packages are linked so it made duplicates of them.

Duplicate packages were generated in MainApplication.java - imports and class initialization.

Also check settings.gradle and build.gradle/app - there might be duplicate packages that will break your application as well.

Answer (score 0):

Add the two important line in your gradle the multidex enablity and the implementation.

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 15 
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}
dependencies {
     implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'  
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

i had this problem using react-native with android 4.4 kit-kat, not only i had to add:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 15 
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
        ...
    }
    
}
dependencies {
     implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:2.0.1'  
  }
```

but also had to add to my MainAplication.java:

`import androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication; // <-- THIS IMPORT`

and change:

`public class MainApplication extends Application  implements ReactApplication`

to:

`public class MainApplication extends MultiDexApplication  implements ReactApplication`

you can find more info here:
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex